# How to convert 10 digits with this format XXX-XXX-XXXX to US formal format that looks like (XXX) XXX-XXXX using Python3 Regex sub

Tags: python-3.x, regex

> This is my try, it actually put the first and seconds groups of 3 digits between parenthesis while I only need to put the first group only between parenthesis to meet US phone number formal format like (XXX) XXX-XXXX.
> I am asked to do this using re.sub only which means it is a pattern matter and correct syntax which I am missing actually.
> Thank you very much.

```
import re 
def convert_phone_number(phone): 
   result = re.sub(r"(\d+-)", r"(\1)", phone) # my actual pattern - change only this line
   return result                              

print(convert_phone_number("My number is 212-345-9999.")) # output should be: My number is (212) 345-9999.
# my actual output: My number is (212-)(345-)9999.
print(convert_phone_number("Please call 888-555-1234")) # output should be: Please call (888) 555-1234
# my actual output: Please call (888-)(555-)1234
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(\d{3})-', r'(\1) ', phone)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U3Z1AM/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand whitespace boundary
- `(\d{3})` - Capturing group #1: three digits
- `-` - a hyphen.

The replacement is the Group 1 value inside round brackets and a space after (that will replace the hyphen).

Answer (score 7):

This result will include the checking part for phone format (it must be XXX-XXX-XXXX), if it correct the re.sub function will pass:

```
import re
def convert_phone_number(phone):
  result = re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4}\b)', r'(\1) \2-\3', phone)
  return result

print(convert_phone_number("My number is 212-345-9999.")) # My number is (212) 345-9999.
print(convert_phone_number("Please call 888-555-1234")) # Please call (888) 555-1234
print(convert_phone_number("123-123-12345")) # 123-123-12345
print(convert_phone_number("Phone number of Buckingham Palace is +44 303 123 7300")) # Phone number of Buckingham Palace is +44 303 123 7300
```

Comment: This is spot on! Can you explain logic for how you got to this regex?

Answer (score 2):

```
re.sub(r"\b\s(\d{3})-", r" (\1) ", phone)
```

Comment: This captures the preceding whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def convert_phone_number(phone):
  result = re.sub(r"\b\s(\d{3})-\b", r" (\1) ", phone)
  return result
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution work also . You use regex grouping in the first parameter to capture the result of the matched pattern. A boundary match **\b** is applied for the 4 last digits to avoid matching numbers with more than 4 digits. The second parameter **r"(\1) \2-\3"** is then used to change and replace the matched string.

```py
import re
def convert_phone_number(phone):
  result = re.sub(r"([\d]{3})-([\d]{3})-([\d]{4}\b)", r"(\1) \2-\3", phone)
  return result

print(convert_phone_number("My number is 212-345-9999.")) # My number is (212) 345-9999.
print(convert_phone_number("Please call 888-555-1234")) # Please call (888) 555-1234
print(convert_phone_number("123-123-12345")) # 123-123-12345
print(convert_phone_number("Phone number of Buckingham Palace is +44 303 123 7300")) # Phone number of Buckingham Palace is +44 303 123 7300
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def convert_phone_number(phone):
  result = re.sub(r" (\d{3})-",r" (\1) ",phone)
  return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
result = re.sub(r"(\b\d[0-9]{2}\b)-(\b[0-9]{3}\b-\b[0-9]{4}\b)", r"(\1) \2", phone)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
result = re.sub(r"(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4}\b)", r"(\1) \2-\3" , phone)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

`result = re.sub(r' ([\d]+)-',r' (\1) ',phone)`

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach: to account for **123-123-12345**, which isn't supposed to have parentheses in the output, I use group `(w* )` and I use `(\d{3})-` so the Buckingham Palace numbers with 3 digits do not get parentheses:

```
result = re.sub(r"(w* )(\d{3})-", r" (\2) ", phone)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import re
def convert_phone_number(phone):
  result = re.sub(r'(.+)(\d{3})-(\d{3}-\d{4})',r'\1(\2) \3',phone)
  return result
''' the regex searches for  any character with more than 1 occurrence,before the phone format, then the replacement regex formats the string'''
print(convert_phone_number("My number is 212-345-9999.")) # My number is (212) 345-9999.
print(convert_phone_number("Please call 888-555-1234")) # Please call (888) 555-1234
print(convert_phone_number("123-123-12345")) # 123-123-12345
print(convert_phone_number("Phone number of Buckingham Palace is +44 303 123 7300")) # Phone number of Buckingham Palace is +44 303 123 7300
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code.