# how to ignore unwanted pattern in regex

Tags: python, regex, pdf-extraction

I have the following python code

```py
from io import BytesIO
import pdfplumber, requests
test_case = {
    'https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/sehk/2020/0514/2020051400555.pdf': 59,
    'https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/gem/2020/0529/2020052902118.pdf': 55,
    'https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/sehk/2020/0618/2020061800366.pdf': 47,
    'https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/gem/2020/0630/2020063002674.pdf': 30,
}

for url, page in test_case.items():
    rq = requests.get(url)
    pdf = pdfplumber.load(BytesIO(rq.content))
    txt = pdf.pages[page].extract_text()
    txt = re.sub("([^\x00-\x7F])+", "", txt)  # no chinese
    pattern = r'.*\n.*?(?P<auditor>[A-Z].+?\n?)(?:LLP\s*)?\s*((PRC.*?|Chinese.*?)?[Cc]ertified [Pp]ublic|[Cc]hartered) [Aa]ccountants'
    try:
        auditor = re.search(pattern, txt, flags=re.MULTILINE).group('auditor').strip()
        print(repr(auditor))
    except AttributeError:
        print(txt)
        print('============')
        print(url)
```

It produces the following result

```
'ShineWing'
'ShineWing'
'Hong Kong Standards on Auditing (HKSAs) issued by the Hong Kong Institute of'
'Hong Kong Financial Reporting Standards issued by the Hong Kong Institute of'
```

The desired result is:

```
'ShineWing'
'ShineWing'
'Ernst & Young'
'Elite Partners CPA Limited'
```

I tried:

`pattern = r'.*\n.*?(?P<auditor>[A-Z].+?\n?)$(?!Institute)(?:LLP\s*)?\s*((PRC.*?|Chinese.*?)?[Cc]ertified [Pp]ublic|[Cc]hartered) [Aa]ccountants'`
This pattern captures the last two cases but not the first 2.

`pattern = r'.*\n.*?(?P<auditor>^(?!Hong|Kong)[A-Z].+?\n?)(?:LLP\s*)?\s*((PRC.*?|Chinese.*?)?[Cc]ertified [Pp]ublic|[Cc]hartered) [Aa]ccountants'`
This produces the desired result but `^(?!Hong|Kong)` is potentially risky because it may ignore other desired results in the future so it is not a good candidate.

Instead, `$(?!Institute)` is more general and appropriate but I have no idea why it couldn't be matched in the first 2 cases. it would be great if there is a way that I could ignore matches that contain `issued by the Hong Kong Institute of`

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I asked same question few days ago and a regex genius answered me https://stackoverflow.com/a/62612757/13824946

Comment: @Cyber-Tech Can you be more specific? I tried `?<!` but it does not make any difference with the 1st pattern $(?!Institute). the last two are not captured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pattern = r'\n.*?(?P<auditor>(?!.*Institute)[A-Z].+?)(?:LLP\s*)?\s*((PRC.*?|Chinese.*?)?[Cc]ertified [Pp]ublic|[Cc]hartered) [Aa]ccountants'
```

This works.